# Minimum without computing the derivative.

Tags: real-analysis, maxima-minima

I am trying to find the minimum of the following function:
$$H(x)=\frac{(x+\frac{1}{x})^6-(x^6+\frac{1}{x^6})-2}{(x+\frac{1}{x})^3+(x^3+\frac{1}{x^3})},\hspace{1cm}x>0$$

What I usually do to find extrema of a function is computing the derivative of the function and finding its zeros. However, I think there must be a more efficient approach to this problem, since the derivative of this function is quite long. Any tips?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\displaystyle \bigg[\bigg(x+\frac{1}{x}\bigg)^3\bigg]^2-\bigg[x^3+\frac{1}{x^3}\bigg]^2$$

$$\bigg[\bigg(x+\frac{1}{x}\bigg)^3+x^3+\frac{1}{x^3}\bigg]\bigg[\bigg(x+\frac{1}{x}\bigg)^3-x^3-\frac{1}{x^3}\bigg]$$

$$H(x)=\bigg(x+\frac{1}{x}\bigg)^3-x^3-\frac{1}{x^3}=3\bigg(x+\frac{1}{x}\bigg)\geq 3\cdot 2=6$$

Because arithmetic geometric inequality

$$x+\frac{1}{x}\geq 2\;\forall \;x>0$$

Comment: You have proved a lower bound, but for completeness note that $x=1$ attains the lower bound.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that
$$H(x) = \frac{\left(\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^3\right)^2 - \left(x^3+\frac{1}{x^3}\right)^2}{\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^3 + \left(x^3+\frac{1}{x^3}\right)} = \left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^3 - \left(x^3+\frac{1}{x^3}\right) = 3\left(x+\frac{1}{x} \right) \geq  6$$
(with equality at $x=1$) where in the last step I have use the inequalities $x>0$ and $(x-1)^2 \geq 0$. On the other hand since $lim_{x \rightarrow 0} H(x) = \infty$, the range of $H$ is $[6, \infty)$.

**Edit:** Typos corrected, thanks to Rob for pointing them out, apologies for the delay.

Comment: You have a sign error after the division.

Comment: Dear callculus, apologies for the sign error, it was entirely unintentional, so kindly refrain from using unnecessarily rude comments on an academic platform, some of us are not online all the time.

Comment: @asrxiiviii Why was my comment rude? It was "*Maybe the comment of Rob was not precise enough for you:* $\frac{a^2−b^2}{a+b}=a−b$ Please make an edit."

Comment: Also $x^2$ should be $x$ after the subtraction.